# Reverse zooming Microsoft Keyboard MSPaint

Tags: windows-7, desktop, wireless-keyboard

A few weeks ago, I've bought a Microsoft Wireless Desktop 2000 set.
On my keyboard, when I use the zoom in/out buttons, they're working fine.
But in MSPaint, they're reversed !
When I press the zoom in button, it zooms out,  and when I press the zoom out button, it zooms in !

Is this a problem in Paint or a problem with my Keyboard?
I don't think it's a problem with my keyboard because I haven't encountered this problem with other programs (yet).

Oh, and yes, I have installed the latest drivers (IntelliType AND IntelliPoint).
And I am using Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the [Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads/mouse-keyboard-center) which replaces the separate IntelliType and IntelliPoint software. For the keyboard set app-specific settings to change the behaviors of the zoom in/out buttons for MSPaint.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that works, but I can't remap the zoom buttons within the "app-specified settings".

While that's what I need to.

Comment: This reads more as a comment rather than an answer to the question. Did you mean to respond to a different answer?